# Window function on large arays

Tags: fft, python, window-functions

Hello I'm reading the following document to better understand windowing and how to use it.

> "Spectrum and spectral density estimation by the Discrete Fourier
>   transform (DFT), including a comprehensive list of window functions
>   and some new  at-top windows."

[You can find the file overhere](http://www.rssd.esa.int/SP/LISAPATHFINDER/docs/Data_Analysis/GH_FFT.pdf)

I try to reproduce their example (chapter 13) on audio signals but i have some questions.
Just like the example i use the Hann(ing) window. with a overlab of 50%
For reproducion i use python

Let say i have a typical Audio signal with a `fs` of `44100 Hz` and a length of `T = 5 sec`. 
I have a window of 0.1 sec(neglecting the nice length of `N`).
With the overlab i get an matrix of 100(Windows) X 4410 Samples.

I have two questions

1. Normaly i see just a single Spectrum plot (exept STFT). How come i from a my set of spectra to a single spectrum? [Like what Audacity have](http://manual.audacityteam.org/o/man/plot_spectrum.html)
   Averaging; summing; ... other
2. what is the impact of changes in time at the resulting spectrum. Let say using a (measured) sweeping signal?

Hope that somebody can help me now

Comment: please can somebody help me?? or tips for better question or split the question?

Comment: Is your doubt related to plotting spectrum(or spectrogam) for entire length of signal, and the effects of window length on spectrogram ?

Comment: the question is basicly... When have a large array of data with a relatively short Window. I get a lot of FFT frames.  Is it possible to mix these frames together to a more narrow FFT and How do I sum up all these frames to make a single spectrum

Comment: I think there is some clarification needed, first of all if you know that your input signal is stationary, then you need not do windowing. and if your signal is non-stationary you should not expect summing-up/adding to get single spectrum, in this case you should observe spectrum for each window(of that particular time instant/window).

Comment: But how does software as Audacity, Ardour, Ableton or Logic pro handle this kind of information? This is always in some $2^N$ sample bins and i think also a window... That software is also not stationary and become one final spectrum.

Comment: Audacity is just averaging over all windows and plotting, because there is option to select a region in entire audio for which you want to plot spectrum

Comment: Oke that is half of the answer i want... 
Are they just averaging ($\frac{\sum_{i=0}^{N-1} FFT_{Spectra} }{N} $) or a more complex method